# How to read motor RPM open collector tach output

Tags: pigpio

I have this motor which has a tach output that I want to use to read motors RPM, [EC centrifugal fan - RadiCal](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1328/0900766b81328e26.pdf).

On page 4 there is a shcematic diagram and it also says Tach output: open collector, 1 pulse per revolution, electrically isolated.

How do I connect tach wire to Pi Zero and which code can I use to read the RPM data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect a Pi ground to the motor ground or tachometer ground.

You then connect the tachometer open collector output to a Pi GPIO.

You need to pull the chosen GPIO up to 3V3 through a resistor.  The resistor value isn't critical.  Anything between 1k and 100k ohms should work.  You could use the internal GPIO pulls which are about 50k ohm.

The GPIO will normally read high (1) but once a motor revolution it will be pulled low (0) by the tachometer.

There is plenty of software to read the GPIO just a google away.

I have written a Python RPM module.

See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_read_RPM_py

Comment: joan thanks for the answe and link to your code. I am now able to read some data using your code. I tried with and without internal pull up resistor by adding "pi.set_pull_up_down(gpio, pigpio.PUD_UP)" but it does  not make any difference. I get different RPM at different fan speeds but they are not matching the specs. at 100 speed it should be 2580 rpm or at leat hear it. Instead I get 970rpm. I use 1 cycle per rev which is default in your code. Any idea why I am getting such a low value?

Comment: I wonder what is wrong. Could there be wrong readings due to internal pullup resistor instead of if I would use external one?

Comment: Could you run http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py and get some representative timings.  Do they support the RPM you expect?

Comment: My bad. It turns out the readings were correct. I wasn't actually getting full speed as I though. I am controlling the motor using PWM and when I set it to 100% it not really a full speed. I found it out when I controlled it with potentiometer then setting to max it just goes like crazy and I got 2500 something rpm.

so with PWM control and at 100% pwm signal the motor actually get up to 30% of its max speed. I need to find out why. Any ideas are welcome.